Spring boot RestClient Get Hangs
I have the following code that works fine for https://google.com but always hangs for https://api.nasdaq.com.
Could someone point me to the potential issues?
RestClient restclient = RestClient.builder()
                                    .baseUrl("https://api.nasdaq.com")
                                    .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                                    .build(); 

ResponseEntity<String> resp = restclient.get().uri("/api/quote/TSLA/historical?assetclass=stocks&fromdate=2024-04-01&limit=9999&todate=2024-04-08").retrieve().toEntity(String.class); 
System.out.println(resp);


There are so many examples online and so many answer from SOF but none seems to work.
This is the log and where it stucks.
2024-04-07T16:01:27.261-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] o.a.h.c.http.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : ex-0000000001 Cookie spec selected: strict
2024-04-07T16:01:27.275-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] o.a.h.c.h.i.classic.InternalHttpClient   : ep-0000000001 start execution ex-0000000001
2024-04-07T16:01:27.275-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] h.i.i.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : ep-0000000001 executing exchange ex-0000000001 over http-outgoing-0
2024-04-07T16:01:27.277-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.headers       : http-outgoing-0 >> GET /api/quote/TSLA/historical?assetclass=stocks&fromdate=2024-04-01&limit=9999&todate=2024-04-08 HTTP/1.1
2024-04-07T16:01:27.277-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.headers       : http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/json
2024-04-07T16:01:27.277-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.headers       : http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate
2024-04-07T16:01:27.277-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.headers       : http-outgoing-0 >> Host: api.nasdaq.com
2024-04-07T16:01:27.277-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.headers       : http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: keep-alive
2024-04-07T16:01:27.277-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.headers       : http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.10)
2024-04-07T16:01:27.278-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 >> "GET /api/quote/TSLA/historical?assetclass=stocks&fromdate=2024-04-01&limit=9999&todate=2024-04-08 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2024-04-07T16:01:27.278-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
2024-04-07T16:01:27.278-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
2024-04-07T16:01:27.278-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: api.nasdaq.com[\r][\n]"
2024-04-07T16:01:27.278-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
2024-04-07T16:01:27.278-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.3 (Java/17.0.10)[\r][\n]"
2024-04-07T16:01:27.278-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [   scheduling-1] org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire          : http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
2024-04-07T16:01:27.588-04:00 DEBUG 2986853 --- [dto] [nio-9400-Poller] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1712520087588; nextExpiration=1712520087576; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false


One reason could be your network has firewall rule to restrict this host as not allowed. If yes then you may have to use proxy server to connect.

No, it isn't network issue. I can get the information via browser.

Your browser already may have proxy setting. Check once…

My browser doesn't have proxy enabled.

In my case RestClient did not get a response due to the header "Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate" that was added. The server (stub) could not handle that.
